# How to get all list items from an unordered list in HTML with JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

How to reach ul list each value by js or jq to use it to reach any parts in html ?

```
var nav = document.getElementsByClassName('navigation'),
item = nav.getElementsbyTagName('li'),
i; 

for(i =0;i<item.length;i++ ){
console.log(item[i].childNodes);
i++;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you want to improve your question, you are trying to get the values of all li elements in an ul ?

Comment: yes, that's meaning

Comment: you already "reach" ,as you said, ul li values. I thnink now you need to explain more what you mean with  "to reach any parts in html"

Answer (score 1):

#### You have some alternatives:

## [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

#### This method returns a NodeList

Suppose you have a simple list you can get the node values like this:

```js
// Get all nodes with querySelectorAll
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('li');

// Iterate over elements
elements.forEach(element => 
  // Add click event to every node
  element.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log(element.innerText);
  }));
  
// Log values
elements.forEach(element => console.log(element.innerText));
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

If you want to reduce the li elements you can assign a class like this:

```js
// Get all nodes with querySelectorAll
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('li.menu');

elements.forEach(element => console.log(element.innerText));
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="menu">1</li>
  <li class="menu">2</li>
  <li class="menu">3</li>
</ul>
```

## [getElementByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

#### This method returns an html collection

Here you can get the same result, but you need to assign a class name to the li elements:

```js
// Get elements by class name
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('menu');

// Iterate over the html collection
for(let i = 0; i < elements.length ; i++){
  
  // Add event listener to click event
  elements[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
  
    // Log values
    console.log(elements[i].innerText);
  })
}

// Log values
for(let i = 0; i < elements.length ; i++){
  console.log(elements[i].innerText);
}
```

```html
<ul>
      <li class="menu">1</li>
      <li class="menu">2</li>
      <li class="menu">3</li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This snippet will help you understand how to capture and use the values inside a `ul` tag. In this example I put the values inside an array and then printed them. This example is completed by ***jQuery***.

```js
let myArray = [];
function putListToMyArray(){
  $('#myUl > li').each(function(){
    myArray.push($(this).text());
  });
  $('#willAppend').html(myArray);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myUl">
  <li>something 1...</li>
  <li>something 2...</li>
  <li>something 3...</li>
  <li>something 4...</li>
  <li>something 5...</li>
</ul>
<button onClick="putListToMyArray()">Put them in an array</button>
<hr />
<span id="willAppend">Array will append here...</span>
```